# How would I use "LEFT JOIN" and "IF NOT EXISTS" in this case?

Tags: join, query, foreign-key, if-not-exists

There're 2 main tables: `drivers` and `driver_riders` that are connected by a foreign key. Every day some of the drivers make a single or multiple rides.

There's also a table `driver_rewards`

```
driver_rewards
---
  ride_id
  reward_percent
  reward_amount
```

A cron job would scan `rides` every other hour, select `status = success` rides and insert a reward record into `driver_rewards`. But  **only those rides that haven't been inserted yet** -- there's been no record with `ride_id = ?` in `driver_rewards` so far, that is.

How to properly create SQL quiery that would select such `rides`? I'm aware of `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` but how would I use them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use an outer join like `LEFT JOIN` here or `NOT EXISTS`  but you don't need both. I prefer outer joins because they feel more relational to me. Here's how you can accomplish your goals with one:

```
SELECT R.* -- Don't use *, it's an anti-pattern. Instead actually list out only the columns you need.
FROM rides AS R -- Start with all rides.
LEFT JOIN driver_rewards AS DR -- Join to driver_rewards...
    ON R.ride_id = DR.ride_id -- by the ride_id...
WHERE dr.ride_id IS NULL -- and filter out the rows where the driver_rewards matched (have dr.ride_id is not null) by only returning where dr.ride_id is null
AND r.status = 'success'
```

---

Note you should:

1. Always tag which database system and version you're using, as the answers to your question can vary either logically or syntactically depending on these things.
2. Always provide the full definitions of all tables involved. I had to guess the names of your columns in the `rides` table.

Comment: That way is usually [worse for performance](https://erikdarlingdata.com/why-not-exists-makes-more-sense-than-left-joins/)

Comment: Haven't you confused the order of the tables? `SELECT FROM driver_rewards .... LEFT JOIN riders AS R ` instead. Not?

Comment: @Camila326 No, the tables are in the proper order. You want *all* `rides` that don't exist in `driver_rewards` yet. To accomplish that with a `LEFT JOIN` you need to put `rides` on the **left** side of the join. The table you don't want to be filtered by the `LEFT JOIN` always goes on the left side. (Also note, Erik's link on performance may or may not apply, depending on your database system. It's an article that is specific to Microsoft SQL Server. But it's a good thing to consider and test.)